# Go server exits with exit code 1

Tags: docker-compose, go-cd

I am trying to run gocd docker image using docker compose. I want to replace existing cruise-config file with a new one.
I am trying to replace existing cruise-config.xml by a new file by copying it in the Dockerfile. I am able to build docker-compose without any errors but when I run the docker-compose file, the go server container starts but exits after few seconds with error code 1.

File: Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
  services:
  go-server:
    build:
      context: go_server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8153:8153'
      - '8154:8154'
    volumes:
    - ./go_server/server_home/config:/go-working-dir/config
```

File: go_server/Dockerfile

```
   FROM gocd/gocd-server:v17.8.0
    RUN mkdir -p /go-working-dir/config
    RUN chmod 777 -R /go-working-dir/config

    COPY ./server_home/config/cruise-config.xml /go-working-dir/config/cruise-config.xml
    COPY ./server_home/config/cruise-config.xml /go-working-dir/config/cruise-config.xml2

    RUN chown -R go:go /go-working-dir /godata

    EXPOSE 8153 8154
```

Am I missing something here? The log file of the container shows no error

```
Logs:
    dailybuild@DockerHost:~$ sudo docker logs 5af1aefa0c9d
    /docker-entrypoint.sh: Creating directories and symlinks to hold GoCD configuration, data, and logs
    $ mkdir -v /godata/artifacts
    $ chown go:go /godata/artifacts
    $ ln -sv /godata/artifacts /go-working-dir/artifacts
    $ chown go:go /go-working-dir/artifacts
    $ mkdir -v /godata/config
    $ chown go:go /godata/config
    $ mkdir -v /godata/db
    $ chown go:go /godata/db
    $ ln -sv /godata/db /go-working-dir/db
    $ chown go:go /go-working-dir/db
    created directory: '/godata/artifacts'
    '/go-working-dir/artifacts' -> '/godata/artifacts'
    created directory: '/godata/config'
    created directory: '/godata/db'
    '/go-working-dir/db' -> '/godata/db'
    created directory: '/godata/logs'
    '/go-working-dir/logs' -> '/godata/logs'
    created directory: '/godata/plugins'
    $ mkdir -v /godata/logs
    $ chown go:go /godata/logs
    $ ln -sv /godata/logs /go-working-dir/logs
    $ chown go:go /go-working-dir/logs
    $ mkdir -v /godata/plugins
    '/go-working-dir/plugins' -> '/godata/plugins'
    created directory: '/godata/addons'
    '/go-working-dir/addons' -> '/godata/addons'
    $ chown go:go /godata/plugins
    $ ln -sv /godata/plugins /go-working-dir/plugins
    $ chown go:go /go-working-dir/plugins
    $ mkdir -v /godata/addons
    $ chown go:go /godata/addons
    $ ln -sv /godata/addons /go-working-dir/addons
    $ chown go:go /go-working-dir/addons
```

Comment: Can you build and run the container without docker-compose but just with docker?

Comment: Even without using docker-compose, I face the same problem. The container exits after few seconds.

Comment: Got it working. The issue was with encryption key. I had to mount all the existing files of go server like jetty.xml,cruise-config.xsd, agentstore,keystore to docker container and then copy the existing cruise-config.xml so that the container uses these files to decrypt the values in cruise-config.xml.